# PulpSolverError: Pulp: Error while trying to execute, use msg=True for more details

Tags: linear-programming, pulp, coin-or-cbc

i use below scripts to load solved problem from JSON.

```
import pulp as lp

d, loaded_problem = lp.LpProblem.fromJson('saved_problem.json')
loaded_problem.solve()
```

it shows

```
At line 1594 ENDATA
Problem MODEL has 341 rows, 50 columns and 704 elements
Coin0008I MODEL read with 0 errors
Continuous objective value is 8.3122 - 0.00 seconds
Cgl0003I 0 fixed, 0 tightened bounds, 15 strengthened rows, 0 substitutions
Cgl0003I 0 fixed, 0 tightened bounds, 10 strengthened rows, 0 substitutions
Cgl0004I processed model has 39 rows, 21 columns (21 integer (0 of which binary)) and 126 elements
Cutoff increment increased from 1e-05 to 0.9999
Cbc0012I Integer solution of 28 found by DiveCoefficient after 0 iterations and 0 nodes (0.01 seconds)
Cbc0038I Full problem 39 rows 21 columns, reduced to 8 rows 11 columns
Cbc0012I Integer solution of 20 found by RINS after 0 iterations and 0 nodes (0.01 seconds)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CoinError'
Exception in execute request:
```

then error out.

the saved json file link:

[saved_problem.json](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/files/13350565/saved_problem.json)

I want to know how to solve this error.